# SQL MAX de multiples columnas

Tags: sql

Tengo esta tabla:

```
ID    NUM      TIPO      CANTIDAD   FECHA 

451   225     36          60000     2018-05-16 

452   225     37          60000     2018-05-16 

453   225     38          00001     2018-05-07 

454   225     39          60000 2018-05-16 

455   225     40          00000      2018-05-07     
456   226     36          00001      2018-05-07     
457   226     37          00001     2018-05-07

458   226     38          00001      2018-05-07 

459   226     39          00001      2018-05-07     
460   226     40    00001        2018-10-28     
461   225     41    00001       2018-05-07  
462   226     41    00001       2018-05-07 

463   225     42    00001       2018-05-09

464   226     42    61000   2018-06-18 

465   225     36    60150   2018-11-17 


466   226     41  3       2018-11-17
```

y quiero obtener los valores máximos de la columna cantidad para cada TIPO y para cada NUM, sin que repitan los tipos. (El ID es un automerico, no sirve para la consulta)

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2):

Los dos `MAX` no pueden aplicarse al mismo tiempo al menos de la forma en que dices: "Sin repetir el tipo", o agrupas por `TIPO` o por `NUM`, agrupar por los dos indefectiblemente te repetirá algunos `TIPO`.

Puedes hacer dos consultas separadas:

```
SELECT TIPO, MAX(CANTIDAD)
       FROM TABLA
       GROUP BY TIPO

SELECT NUM, MAX(CANTIDAD)
       FROM TABLA
       GROUP BY NUM
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías apoyarte en la claúsula OVER para consultas analíticas (que se realizan en paralelo con la tabla del FROM) de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT ID, 
      MAX(CANTIDAD) OVER (GROUP BY NUM) AS NUM, 
      MAX(CANTIDAD) OVER (GROUP BY TIPO) AS TIPO,
      CANTIDAD,
      FECHA
FROM TABLA
```

Si te fijas el MAX() de cada OVER va a realizar la misma consulta que hace externamente sobre la tabla pero con ciertas especificaciones, en este caso, se agruparán esas subconsultas por la columna que te interesaría respectivamente y luego te calcularía el máximo de la columna CANTIDAD.

Teoría del mismo por si lo precisas: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples